# Windows Phone 8 - Device Management

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I am a newbie in Windows Phone development. Could someone please help me with the below questions with respect to Windows Phone 8.

1. Company Hub: I assume that this will be a custom application that works as a store/catalog for other company applications (plus additional company information). This has to be developed either by the company itself, or by a vendor for the company. Please correct me if I am wrong.
2. Company Hub is invoked by going to Settings ->Company Apps. Again, please correct me.
3. In some videos, I have seen people logging into "Company Apps" by clicking on an "Add Account" button (Settings ->Company Apps). What is this account? It just asks for an email address and password.
4. How is MDM (Mobile Device Management) implemented in WP8 devices? Is it using the WNS (Windows Notification Services), just like Apple's APNS? Is there a documentation available for implementing MDM in WP8?
5. If this is handled using WNS, then what actions can be performed on a remote Windows Phone 8 device? Is there available a list of commands?
6. Saw few examples using Exchange ActiveSync. Some product companies have their own Administration Portal to setup ActiveSync configurations. How can this be done?

Comment: With the feature to highlight existing apps it IMHO will be more like the existing feature - hence a private company compartment in the Windows Phone 8 app marketplace which is not publicly visible/accessible.

Answer (score 4):

1. You are correct
2. You are correct
3. AFAIK the company account is autodetected, based on the email address that user provides. Companies must get certificate from Symantec in order to use Company Apps. Check out also [Applications Enrollment Token from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735576%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
4. Documentation for MDM API is currently (09.Nov 2012) not yet publicly available.
5. You can check out press releases from MobileIron or AirWatch - see what they promise - that covers the API possibilities

Update: Google 2WP8_Enterprise_Device_Management_Protocol.pdf".

Answer (score 0):

The Settings->Company Apps is where you add your company's hub but once you add it it will show up as an app in the app list and can be pinned to the start screen.

It's basically an app that can be used to show information and install other apps

Users in your company will need to authenticate themselves to get your company app. I'm not sure about the details there